# Should I fill 3/4-inch gaps along the wall before laying ceramic tile?

Tags: joints

We put down two layers of 3/8" plywood over planks (tar paper over planks).  Some of our expansion joints are up to 3/4" at the walls.  Should I fill them with something?

Comment: "Expansion joints", eh? *wink wink*

Comment: @isherwood The questioner was pretty clear on calling them "expansion joints"; the question is whether 3/4" of expansion joint is too much.

Comment: Yep, got all that. I gave a wink because subfloor sheathing is usually rigidly installed with no expansion joint needed or implemented. I suspect hasty cuts. Just a bit of ribbing. (If there's that much movement, tile is a bad idea anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't bother for two reasons. One, it's unlikely that there will ever be any load placed on the tile close enough to the wall to cause breakage. Two, you may be installing baseboard trim or base shoe, which will cover most of that gap anyway.

If you have reasons to disagree, fill the gap with mortar as you tile. Consider laying a row of fiberglass tape along the wall to help prevent cracking.

Comment: I agree with filling with mortar unless a wide base board is used. Mortar would provide a good base for grout when you tile then no one but you will know there was a gap.

Answer (score 0):

First - 3/8" times 2 is the very minimum for a bathroom getting ceramic tiles.  3/8" plywood has a lot of play and is flimsy.  Stacking it hardly makes a good substrate.  This is dependent on the joists below and load but for the most part I would not tile on that.  I would put a 1/2" of durarock over what you have.

Second - Your question...  No issues with that.  Your tile will cover that as you should generally try to tile about 1/4" from wall.  You may need to lay more thinset down.  I would also "test these areas while laying the tile as your tile should not tip if pressure is put on the side.  This isn't really about people walking and stuff like that but often in bathroom a pole or cabinet might push on the edges.   I don't foresee any issues at all but just in case the 3/4" is a little bigger, you just need to fill the void so that your tile lays flat.

Comment: Thanks, guys!  I hadn't thought about the trim.  And - of course it was shoddy cutting.

Comment: Ditto on the statement about 3/8" times 2 is too flimsy. Then there is the fact that very often these days plywood of nominal sizes is actually 1/32" thinner than the nominal dimension. In other words that plywood is likely to be 11/32". Add up that twice and you are a sixteenth thinner than 3/4".

Comment: @MichaelKaras - you are right.  Big boxes by me don't even sell 3/8" true.  Also unless they glued them there is no way staples or nails hold things this thin together well.

Comment: And on a side note, once I've put thinset into expansion joints, how are they still expansion joints?

Comment: We would normal shove a piece of plywood or even cardboard - shipping box - on the edges until everything sets and pull it out.  People cut corners around edges in bathrooms all the time.   Again I think the main issue you have is the plywood isn't thick enough for tile.  Bathrooms make things worse for this too as they get hot and cold more than the rest of the house and more moisture of course.  I would think yours will crack pretty bad within a couple years.

Comment: BTW - kitchen, not bathroom.

Comment: Maureen - how big is your kitchen and what is underneath it?  Also are you tiling first then cabinets or tiling around the cabinets?  And if tiling around the cabinets did you also leave 3/4" around them?

Comment: Kitchen is about 5x12.  The good kind, where you can reach everything by standing in the middle!  16" joist spacing, 1x6 diagonal planks, new tar paper.  Two layers of 3/8" plywood (laid in opposite directions).  And now Ditra.  It feels very solid.  Glass of water in the middle barely ripples at all.  Cabinets have not been removed.  Fridge and stove removed.  Yes, 3/4 inch approximately around cabinets.  Not consistently, just made several errors cutting.